# Flink Java MongoSink set Dynamic collection name

Tags: java, mongodb, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm new to Apache Flink. I wrote, in Java, with the help of the documentation, the following code that reads data in json from a Kafka topic.

I'm able with the following code to put the data in a MongoDb's collection if I set a static collection name. Now, I have a field called collectionName in my ObjectFromKafka object. How i could set the collection name getting it from the mentioned aboved field of my ObjectFromKafka?

```
        KafkaSource<ObjectFromKafka> kafkaSource = KafkaSource.<ObjectFromKafka>builder() //
                .setTopics(properties.getProperty(TOPIC_READ)) //
                .setProperties(properties) //
                .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.committedOffsets(OffsetResetStrategy.EARLIEST)) //
                .setValueOnlyDeserializer(new JsonDeserializationSchema<>(ObjectFromKafka.class)) //
                .build();

        DataStream<ObjectFromKafka> stream = env.fromSource(kafkaSource, WatermarkStrategy.forMonotonousTimestamps(),
                "kafka_source");

        MongoSerializationSchema<ObjectFromKafka> serializationSchema = (input,
                context) -> new InsertOneModel<>(BsonDocument.parse(convertToJsonString(input)));

        MongoSink<ObjectFromKafka> sink1 = MongoSink.<ObjectFromKafka>builder() //
                .setUri("mongodb://username:password@mongo:27017/") //
                .setDatabase("admin") //
                .setCollection("myCollection") //
                .setBatchSize(1000) //
                .setBatchIntervalMs(1000) //
                .setMaxRetries(3) //
                .setDeliveryGuarantee(DeliveryGuarantee.AT_LEAST_ONCE) //
                .setSerializationSchema(serializationSchema) //
                .build();

        stream.sinkTo(sink1).name("mongoDb Sink");
```

I'm unable to find a solution for now.

Thanks in advance.